# TCPDump on rooted android devices

Tags: android, tcpdump

I would like to do TCPDump on rooted android devices.

I would like to create a ".pcap" file for later analysis that will capture upload / download packets.
Is there a good library for this? 
How should I begin ?

Comment: StackOverflow is more about solving issues with solutions/code you have already tried is NOT about other people getting the job done for you

Comment: i only asked for guidance..
not for other people to solve my problems..

Comment: Easy guys see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

First you should get tcpdump.dat file and push it to the phone by following steps.

adb root

adb remount

**adb push local_path_to_tcpdumpt.dat /system/xbin/**

**adb shell chmod 777 system/xbin/tcpdump**

Run the below command at the adb prompt to start capturing the log

**adb shell tcpdump -i any -s 0 -w /sdcard/capture.pcap**

After capturing tcp logs. Pull the pcap file

**adb pull /sdcard/capture.pcap capture.pcap**

Comment: thanks for the comment.
is it possible to run this command:
"adb shell tcpdump -i any -s 0 -w /sdcard/capture.pca"
from the device itself (from a java class, when running an android app) ?
i tried, but i get the following error:
"tcpdump: Can't open netlink socket 13:Permission denied"

Comment: Did you add the required permission to use SOCKETS to your manifest of the android app ?

Comment: you mean this one ?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
if so, then yes.

Comment: @ben you should execute above code as su. You can try installing a terminal emulator for android and run the command directly from there and check if it works.

Comment: i tried using terminal emulator, i still get permissions error from it...